# Visual Studio no me deja escribir en consola

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estoy empezando en c++, en Visual Studio Code. El problema es que quiero que la variable lea por teclado lo que yo le escriba, pero cuando llega al `std::cin >> *variable*` e intento poner algo en consola, no escribe nada. Pulso teclas pero no se pone lo que tecleo en la variable. Código:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int entero;

    std::cout << "Inserta numero";
    std::cin >> entero;

    std::cout << entero;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Y como salida, simplemente da: `Inserta numero:`, y lo dicho, a partir de ahí no me detecta nada que le escriba por teclado.

Comment: Debería funcionar. La unica observación es que el entero lo va a pedir en la misma linea que el `cout` anterior.  Luego no veo nada  que pueda ocasionar lo que dices quizá el problema en el entorno Visual Studio Code. El input de repente te está pidiendo por otro lado. Para comprobar genera el ejecutable, abres una venta de comando, te ubicas donde el archivo.exe y lo ejecutas, verás que sí funciona.

Comment: Prueba `std::cout << entero << "\n";`

Comment: Con que no te detecta lo que escribes por el teclado. Te refieres a que lo que
escbribes no se mira en la terminal, o a que si se mira pero luego no se mira el
cout?

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente sea un problema de que se está cerrando la ventana cuando termina la ejecución del código, pon justo antes del "return 0;" lo siguiente:

```
std::cin.get();

return 0;
```

Y así cuando le des a enter al introducir el texto aparecerá el contenido del cout que has puesto y se quedará esperando a otro cin, es bastante útil para que no se cierre la ventana y así verificar los resultados, hay otras formas usando "getchar();" o incluso "system("pause");" pero en tu caso para no agregar funciones nuevas poniendo otro cin bastará.

Answer (score 1):

a mi me pasaba lo mismo pero lo resolví así...
ya estando en el código en la pestaña de "file" busca
-"preferences,
-luego "settings",
-escribe "run in terminal"
-en lo que te despliega busca un titulo que dice "Code-runner:run in terminal" y selecciona el cuadrito, va a palomearse.
-salir de settings y cierra tambien el programa de visual studio code
-vuelve a abrir el programa y ahora pon en "run" y se va a ver en "terminal" todo, y ya podrás escribir!